# How to Join with select top

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with the combination of multiple tables.
My SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM CRM.Bank as a
JOIN CRM.Documents as b ON a.Bank_ID = b.Documents_ID
JOIN CRM.Counterparties as c ON c.Counterparties_ID = b.Documents_ID
JOIN CRM.Items as d ON d.Document_tran_ID = b.Documents_ID
```

I have table CRM.Items, which has the following columns:

```
Item_ID     Document_tran_ID    Name
=======     ================    ====
1           1                   Advertising banner
2           1                   Shipping costs
3           2                   Garden tent
4           2                   Additional fasteners
5           2                   Shipping costs
```

And now I have a problem how to connect only the first items to the document (d.Document_tran_ID = b.Documents_ID ) ??
I know I should use SELECT TOP. However, I have a problem with creating the correct query

Expect the result in the form of:

```
Bank_ID     Documents_ID        Counterparties_ID       Document_tran_ID    Name
=======     ============        =================       ================    ====
22          1                   4                       1                   Advertising banner
23          2                   20                      2                   Garden tent
24          3                   21                      3                   Other
```

Only the first Item from the document is matched.

Comment: What is your expected result? Could you edit your question to add that?

Comment: Column aliases as a, b, c etc aren't very useful. Chose aliases that at least make some sense. For example b for bank, cp for counterparties.

Comment: `join (select MAX(Document_TRAN_ID)  Document_TRAN_ID, Name from CRM.Items group by Name) d on d.document_tran_id = b.Documents_id`

Comment: @erdys: In your body question you've written My Sql but the tag is Sql Server. Which is the DBMS?

Comment: @Joe Taras: This is just "My SQL query" (as opposed to your SQL query or their SQL query), not "MySQL query".

Comment: Must say, I wonder if the fields that are joined on are correct.  For example, based on the naming I would assume that Bank_ID is the primary key of Bank, and Documents_ID is the primary key of Documents.  So is joining those 2 tables on `a.Bank_ID = b.Documents_ID` correct?  I would expect something like `a.Bank_ID = b.Bank_ID ` instead.

Comment: @erdys: Ok, my fault sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try to use **CROSS APPLY** join. In the inner query, you can apply order condition for selecting **TOP** row

```
SELECT *
FROM CRM.Bank as a
JOIN CRM.Documents as b ON a.Bank_ID = b.Documents_ID
JOIN CRM.Counterparties as c ON c.Counterparties_ID = b.Documents_ID
CROSS APPLY
  (select top 1 * from CRM.Items i where  i.Document_tran_ID = b.Documents_ID) as d
```

Answer (score 0):

use sub-query for documents table

```
SELECT *
FROM CRM.Bank as a
JOIN ( select min(Document_tran_ID) as Documents_ID from CRM.Documents) as b ON a.Bank_ID = b.Documents_ID
JOIN CRM.Counterparties as c ON c.Counterparties_ID = b.Documents_ID
JOIN CRM.Items as d ON d.Document_tran_ID = b.Documents_ID
```